# Angular change image based on dynamical value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Here is my below code

I am doing only if then else condition i want to do if else if if condition based on three value i want to change the image

```
<img [src]="status.getRequestStatus() == 'granted' ? 'assets/imgs/trafficlight_green.png':'assets/imgs/trafficlight_red.png' " class="image--background" >
```

this is for `if and else` condition i want to add `if else if if`

like   `if(new){someimage}else if(new1){some image1} if(new2){some image2}`

Comment: I think that if you use `[(src)]="sourceProperty"` changes based on that, and I would deffenitly move that logic to the component from the view, and on the status.getRequestStatus() you can set the property based on the result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `img` tag on condition as below -

```
<img *ngIf="new" [src]="assets/imgs/trafficlight_green1.png" class="image--background">
<img *ngIf="new1" [src]="assets/imgs/trafficlight_green2.png" class="image--background">
<img *ngIf="new2" [src]="assets/imgs/trafficlight_green3.png" class="image--background">
```

Or use a variable to store image source in your `component.ts` and then bind it in `component.html` as below -

```
<img [src]="imageSource" class="image--background">
```

Answer (score 2):

Move logic to component.

In your `component.html`

```
<img [src]="someFn()" class="image--background" >
```

In your `component.ts`

```
someFn() {
    let rtn = '';
    if(...) {
        rtn = ...
    } else if (...) {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the ternary statement in the template if you wanted to with the if else flow, as a ternary can be chained. It could look like so.

```
<img [src]="'new' ? 'green.png': new1 ? 'red.png' : 'amber.png'" class="image-background">
```

This would read like

```
if (new)
{ 'green.png' }

else if (new1)
{ 'red.png' }

else 
{ 'amber.png' } // being new2
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution based on my comment:

Check the example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-img-src-so)

The validation is made on the component, on your getRequestStatus() I used ngOnInit with a timeout to change "dynamically"

the source is automatically updated based on the source property change.

view:

```
<img [(src)]="sourceImage" width="200" />
```

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  sourceImage: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sourceImage = 'https://angular.io/assets/images/logos/angular/angular.svg';

    setTimeout(()=> {
        this.sourceImage = 'https://dwglogo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/AngularJS_logo_004.svg';
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```